# Finding minimum value more efficiently in racket

Tags: racket

Hello,

I am working on some Racket practice. I am aware that Racket has a built in min function, but I am trying to write one from scratch. I have done some work and found some ideas online, but the code is not very efficient. I am thinking I will need to use a helper method. I am a bit lost on how to further modify this code to make it efficient. I ran this code on the test case shown and it took way too long. On smaller test cases the code does return the correct results. Any suggestions would be great.

```
(define (minim lst)
    (cond 
      ((null? (cdr lst)) (car lst))
      ((< (car lst) (minim (cdr lst))) (car lst))
      (else 
        (minim (cdr lst)))) )
```

(minim '(3 4 2 9 3 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 2 1 3 2 2 2 3 4))

Would return 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming an unsorted list, the most natural way to find the minimum would be to go through the entire list, comparing each element against some initial min value, and whenever an element is smaller than that min, the element gets saved as the new min. At the end, min gets returned when list becomes empty (base case).

For example, consider the following:

```
(define (minimum lst acc)
  (cond
    ((null? lst) acc)
    ((< (car lst) acc)
     (minimum (cdr lst) (car lst)))
    (else
     (minimum (cdr lst) acc))))

(define (mymin lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      #f
      (minimum (cdr lst) (car lst))))
```

`mymin` takes `O(n)` time to find min value in a list, using `n-1` comparisons, where n is the number of elements in list.

You can test this with longer and shorter lists locally:

```
(mymin   '(3 4 2 9 3 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 2 1 3 2 2 2 3 4
           3 4 2 9 3 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 2 1 3 2 2 2 3 4
           3 4 2 9 3 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 2 1 3 2 2 2 3 4
           3 4 2 9 3 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 2 1 3 2 2 2 3 4
           3 4 2 9 3 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 2 1 3 2 2 2 3 4
           3 4 2 9 3 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 2 1 3 2 2 2 3 4
           3 4 2 9 3 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 2 1 3 2 2 2 3 4
           3 4 2 9 3 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 2 1 3 2 2 2 3 4
           3 4 2 9 3 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 2 1 3 2 2 2 3 4
           3 4 2 9 3 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 2 1 3 2 2 2 3 4
           3 4 2 9 3 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 2 1 3 2 2 2 3 4
           3 4 2 9 3 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 2 1 3 2 2 2 3 4
           3 4 2 9 3 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 2 1 3 2 2 2 3 4
           3 4 2 9 3 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 2 1 3 2 2 2 3 4
           3 4 2 9 3 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 2 1 3 2 2 2 3 4
           3 4 2 9 3 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 2 1 3 2 2 2 3 4
           3 4 2 9 3 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 2 1 3 2 2 2 3 4
           3 4 2 9 3 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 2 1 3 2 2 2 3 4
           3 4 2 9 3 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 2 1 3 2 2 2 3 4
           3 4 2 9 3 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 2 1 3 2 2 2 3 4
           3 4 2 9 3 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 2 1 3 2 2 2 3 4 -1))
=> -1
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I now understand that the original code was going through the entire list every single time, instead of updating the new minimum value as you have shown. Thank you for taking the time out and explaining this to me.

Answer (score 3):

The code runs longer than it needs to because for each item in the list, `minim` is called recursively on the `cdr` in the test condition. It has what known as [tree recursion](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node16.html).

A more "Rackety" way to write `minim` might be to define a simple function that compares two numbers:

```
(define (min-of-2 x y)
  (if (< x y)
      x
      y))
```

And then **fold** it over the list using `foldl`:

```
(define (minim lst)
  (foldl min-of-2 (first lst) (rest lst)))
```

The time to use [foldl](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=foldl#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29) is when an operation over a list produces a single value based on the contents of the list as is the case here.

The function `min-of-2` need not be given a name and can be passed as a `lamda`. For example:

```
(define (minim lst)
  (foldl 
    (lambda (x y) (if (< x y) x y))
    (first lst)
    (rest lst)))
```